# Default function arguments and the One Definition Rule

Tags: c++, default-arguments, one-definition-rule

I'm asking this question because I haven't had any luck figuring out exactly how to google for it.

The question is, if I have something like this in a library:

```
#ifdef PROVIDE_DEFAULT_ARG
#define DEFAULT_ARG(v) = v
#else
#define DEFAULT_ARG()
#endif

void Foo(int a, int b DEFAULT_ARG(1));
```

And the library is compiled without defining `PROVIDE_DEFAULT_ARG`, and then the program using the library is compiled *with* it defined (or vice versa), does this violate the One Definition Rule?

Comment: I do not see any definitions. There is only a function declaration.

Comment: That's just a declaration, so it would definitely not violate the ODR. It might have a linker "method not defined" error, though I suspect it would work. I have no idea if it's well defined or not.

Comment: This is all a bit tricksy, why do you want to do it?

Comment: I think this is ok _"...At the point of a function call, the defaults are a union of the defaults provided in all visible declarations for the function. ..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments

Comment: @RichardCritten "A union" - interesting

Comment: Even if it is allowed, you can easily cause ODR violations in places that call `Foo` this way. You may not call the function in a way that would use the default argument in any entity's definition that would be defined in both translation units (e.g. `inline` functions, templates or classes).

Comment: But practically speaking, I don't see how it would go wrong. The default argument is evaluated at the call site and I don't think it normally has any ABI impact.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There is a definition for a default argument: https://wg21.link/basic.def.odr#1.6

Comment: @Artyer And where is there its redefinition?

Answer (score 2):

The ODR only applies when you have more than one definition. You only have one definition of the default argument: in the program using the library. It cannot possibly conflict with the library's translation unit which doesn't have any definition for the default argument.